# Resamples - Error in Model %in% models : object 'Model' not found

Tags: r, diff, resampling, caret

I am trying to evaluate different models using the function resamples. All the models have been previously defined and obtained without any major issues. When executing the resamples function with them, the following error message appears in the screen :

> Error in Model %in% models : object 'Model' not found

**The R chunk has the following structure:**

```
    remuestreos <-
     resamples(list(
                LM = modelo_lm,
                CRT = modelo_cart,
                RFT = modelo_rf,
                NET= modelo_nnet,
                KNN = modelo_knn,
                SVM = modelo_svmRadial,
                BAG = modelo_bagg
                GBM = modelo_gbm))

    dotplot(remuestreos)

    diferencias <- diff(remuestreos)

    summary(remuestreos)
```

**The output after its execution**

> Error in Model %in% models : object 'Model' not found

Can anybody give me a hand to clarify the reason for this error and how to manage it properly?

Best regards

Comment: You're missing a comma after modelo_bagg

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks a lot for your comment. Unfortunatly I did not write the comma when describing the error in my post. The R chunck has the comma and when executing it I got back the error message. Any suitable suggestion?. BR

Comment: I can't duplicate the error with what you have given.  I don't see anywhere in the caret::resamples code where Model %in% models is used.  Try `debugonce(resamples)`, run your code and trace through it as it executes.

Comment: <pre> <code> remuestreos <- resamples(list(LM = modelo_lm,

Comment: Hi Brian,. It seems that the issue does not have to be with resamples itself, but with It  with the function. Using debugonce as you suggested, the code stops when executing dotplot. At that point appears the message: Model %in% models. I have tried executing the diff function before the dotplot one. It does not work and I got back the following error message: "Error in t.test.default(x, ...) : not enough 'x' observations". Does it provide you with any additional insight to suggest me how to proceed?. My data base has more than 1700 data. BR